# Twitsted ValueError: Unknown ECC curve on Raspian Stretch

Tags: scrapy, twisted, raspbian

I want to use my Raspberry Pi 3, running Rapian Stretch for a web scraping project. For python i use the berryconada distribution.
When I run my Spider, I get

```
ValueError: Unknown ECC curve
```

On my Laptop (Xubuntu 16.04) everything runs fine. Maybe I need to install an additional library or something?

Down below the full traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1384, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/home/pi/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 393, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/home/pi/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
  File "/home/pi/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 45, in mustbe_deferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/pi/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/__init__.py", line 65, in download_request
    return handler.download_request(request, spider)
  File "/home/pi/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 63, in download_request
    return agent.download_request(request)
  File "/home/pi/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 300, in download_request
    method, to_bytes(url, encoding='ascii'), headers, bodyproducer)
  File "/home/pi/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 1633, in request
    endpoint = self._getEndpoint(parsedURI)
  File "/home/pi/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 1617, in _getEndpoint
    return self._endpointFactory.endpointForURI(uri)
  File "/home/pi/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 1494, in endpointForURI
    uri.port)
  File "/home/pi/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/contextfactory.py", line 59, in creatorForNetloc
    return ScrapyClientTLSOptions(hostname.decode("ascii"), self.getContext())
  File "/home/pi/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/contextfactory.py", line 56, in getContext
    return self.getCertificateOptions().getContext()
  File "/home/pi/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/contextfactory.py", line 51, in getCertificateOptions
    acceptableCiphers=DEFAULT_CIPHERS)
  File "/home/pi/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/deprecate.py", line 792, in wrapped
    return wrappee(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1595, in __init__
    self._ecCurve = _OpenSSLECCurve(_defaultCurveName)
  File "/home/pi/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1744, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Unknown ECC curve.")
```

Comment: This looks like openssl cipher issue. Can you update all system packages to latest and then try again?

Comment: I already did that befor installing scrapy. Did it again, but the error does not change. If it helps openssl is on version 1.1.0f-3.

Comment: Open an issue with scrapy and twisted, this is probably have to do with some cipher being not available

Comment: Any followup on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dropped berryconda and pip installed scrapy. If you're getting this error on Jessie, moving to Stretch gives you access to the newer openssl libs which contain the missing things.

After I upgraded to Stretch I cut berryconda from my path, pip uninstalled cryptography, twisted, pyopenssl, and scrapy.

Then with the no cache option I pip installed scrapy, which brought all those packages back, and now my spider is running.